# How to click on a Label without identification

Tags: protractor

I have a javascript controlled switch "button" with the following structure:

```
<span class="customSwitch">
    <label tabindex="0" class="selected-option">Relative</label>
    <label tabindex="0">Absolute</label>
</span>
```

And looking for a way to click on Absolute label with Protractor

Comment: Okay, I found it very easy
element(by.cssContainingText('label', 'Absolute')).click()

Answer (score 0):

Another method you can use to solve this issue is by creating a custom XPath for  this label which will be like this

```
element(by.xpath("//span[@class='customSwitch']//label[contains(.,'Absolute')]").click();
```

Hope this helps to resolve the issue

Comment: what about css?